# Draggable + css transform

Tags: jquery, transform, css

Есть див с `#can`, внутри него есть див с `.stick`  При использовании `jQuery UI`, а конкретно его метода `.draggable({containment:'parent'})` все хорошо, и `.stick` не вылезает за границы `#can`. НО. если к `.stick` применено `transform: rotate(45deg)`, он начинает вылезать за края `#can` углами и всем, чем только можно.  
Как исправить данное недоразумение?

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle!

Comment: Отступы допустимы?